# Pattern Java - Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I need to do a college exercise that is as follows: Validate with regular expressions any word that contains exactly two 'a' characters and two 'b' characters or more. I made the following expression in the `Pattern` class:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("a{2}b{2,}");
```

This pattern only validates expressions that begin with two 'a' characters and then two or more 'b' characters. But the exercise requires that the two characters a can be anywhere in the sentence and not necessarily at the beginning, as well as the 'b' characters. How do I do this regular expression

Comment: Can you give some examples & expected matches?

Comment: Unclear requirements. Do you only have a and b chars; or what else is allowed?

Comment: Is it allowed to use more than one regular expression? Then you could just split your expression and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

**Resolution**

```
(a.*){2}b.*b|(b.*){2}a.*a|(a.*b|b.*a){2}
```

**Explanation**

`(a.*){2}b.*b` search for sentences that have `a` followed by `a`, after `b` followed by `b`.

`(b.*){2}a.*a` search for sentences that have `b` followed by `b`, after `a` followed by `a`.

`(a.*b|b.*a){2}` search `a` followed by `b` ou `b` followed by `a`.

Comment: Please add some explanation of what you did, this is not a proper answer

Comment: And what is the point of using a character class  like `[b]` ... with just one entry? That could be written as `b` ?!

Comment: This won't work, because for example `b.*` in the first part might match another `a`, which is not allowed.

Comment: @AlvaroAugusto it matches to `bbaaa` how is it OK?

Answer (score 1):

From `Pattern` you get a `Matcher`, which has two methods:

> `public boolean matches()`
>
> Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.
>
> `public boolean find()`
>
> Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.
>
> This method starts at the beginning of this matcher's region, or, if a previous invocation of the method was successful and the matcher has not since been reset, at the first character not matched by the previous match.

You may use your original pattern and just call `find` instead of `matches`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("a{2}b{2,}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myStringToBeSearchedForPattern);
if (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println("Found!");
}
```

However, depending on the requirements you have to modify your pattern. From your description it is unclear what the exact requirements are (Can `a{2}` and `b{2,}` be in any order? Are there other characters then `a` and `b`?)